# Why don't bones appear when I add them?

Tags: rigging, 3d-view, armature, bones

I have a problem applying bones to my models.

When I select the option to add a bone or armature, it does not appear in any of the models in the working screen of the program.

I've already activated the addons, tried to uncheck the "hidden" option, activated the viewport display (in front), restarted the computer and reinstalled the program but nothing seems to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Did you also check if the Bones box under Objects is checked in Viewport Overlays? (There's a dropdown menu next to the small icon of a circle in front of a white circle, usually found in in the top right corner of the 3D Viewport)

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
That solved the problem!!!

Comment: Hi. Please don't add 'solved' to the title. A question can be marked as solved by 'accepting' an answer. As you don't have any answers yet you can either add your own solution in the answer box below or ask @Fjoersteller to add an answer with the solution they proposed in their comment and then 'accept' it. Thanks.

Comment: Often i see a comment being sufficient but for good measure I'll turn it into a answer then. : )  (If nothing else i guess it's also better to be of the Unanswered list)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Bones box under Objects is checked in Viewport Overlays. (There's a dropdown menu next to the small icon of a circle in front of a white circle, usually found in in the top right corner of the 3D Viewport.)